# Liquid filter access itself within pipe chain

Tags: shopify, template-engine, liquid

This works:

```
{% assign getWord = "hello world" | split: " " %}
{% assign getWord = getWord[0] %}
{{ getWord }}
```

I was just wondering if the same thing could be done in one line something like this:

```
{% assign getWord = "hello world" | split: " " | this[0] %}
{% assign getWord = "hello world" | split: " " [0] %}
{% assign getWord = "hello world" | split: " " | [0] %}
{% assign getWord = "hello world" | split: " " | getWord[0] %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will solve your exact problem where you need to access index 0 and the last index.

```
{% assign getWord1 = "hello world" | split: " " | first %}
<!-- Test 1: {{ getWord1 }} == hello -->
{% assign getWord2 = "hello world" | split: " " | last %}
<!-- Test 2: {{ getWord2 }} == world -->
{% assign getWord3 = "hello world" | first %}
<!-- Test 3: {{ getWord3 }} == h -->
```

Comment: This is great, what about access to index 1? Any way to get to that, or only `first` and `last`?

Comment: As far I know there is no way to access random index. If you need to do this from the single line you should be able to remove parts of the string with the remove: "my expression" filter, but I'm not sure what would be the purpose of that. Assigning variable[5] on the second line seems to be much cleaner solution. Someone should submit patch to liquid filters that does index: count array access :)